# How to disable the SSO feature in the Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, idp

I want to use Keycloak as an identity provider in our company.

I have defined one Realm with three clients (I have three applications and I have defined a client for each application)

I want to separate the process of login and logout for each application. For example when I login into app1 and app2 and app3, and then logout from app1, the app2 and app3 remain logged in.

In StackOverflow I found some solution to separate the login process for each application as follow:

```
 1. in admin console, go to Authentication
 2. make a copy of Browser flow
 3. in this new flow, disable or delete Cookie
 4. go to Clients -> (your client) -> Authentication Flow Overrides, change Browser Flow to your new flow, click Save."
```

[How to force login per client with keycloak (¿best practice?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048205/how-to-force-login-per-client-with-keycloak-best-practice?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

But this solution is not working for making the logout process independent for each application(which means I want to disable the SSO feature in Keycloak). Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: Usually this is what realms are designed for. Think about Google services.. you log in once in your google account and can access any of the service. If you logout from your google account, then you can't anymore. So maybe you want to have a realm per application.

Comment: If I use different Realm for each application, I need to define users and roles again for every Realm. I want to have my basic login page and have an alternative option to login with keycloak(I want keycloak to behave an external idp just like facebook and google) Is it possible?

Comment: If you use keycloak as an external idp, when loging out from it you'll be logged out in all your clients in that realm (the same that happens when using google). The alternative might be to use `Direct Access Grants` as @Jan Garaj points out, so you grab the token from your application and you manage the session (this way you avoid having one user management per application).

Comment: @Maryam Any update on this? It would be great if you can provide me with any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would enable `Direct Access Grants` on the client level only (`Standard Flow` will be disabled), so applications will have to use direct grant flow. No IdP sessions in the user browser will be created in this case, so no SSO will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. As you said, in my application clients, I disabled the Standard Flow and left Direct Access Grants, Service Account, and Authorization enabled. Now when I want to be redirected to the Keycloak login page, Bad Request will appear. the error in URL is: 192.168.x.x:8080/authz-app2?error=unauthorized_client&error_description=Client+is+not+allowed+to+initiate+browser+login+with+given+response_type.+Standard+flow+is+disabled+for+the+client.

Comment: @MarYam check documentation how `direct grant flow` works, you can't use Keycloak login page in this case, otherwise you will have IdP session = SSO