# Connecting keycloak with Active Directory with SAML IDP sends empty response

Tags: active-directory, keycloak, saml-2.0

We have a problem connecting keycloak (version 9) with an Active Directory IDP (version3) with SAML: the Azure IDP responds with an empty status response, although we have configured the response attibutes.

Sometimes it works, but most time it produces a login loop. As far as I could see, there is no login performed (no login screen) but the login information from the system is used. (Browseer is firefox)

The SAML response looks like this:

```
<samlp:Response ID="_1629646f-f163-4ba1-beaa-58c44bc14494"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="2021-12-20T07:23:37.407Z"
                Destination="https://keycloak.mydomain/auth/realms/CUSTOMER/broker/saml/endpoint"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                InResponseTo="ID_d2e30a9a-7f0c-4811-a88c-b1cbebc3329b"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                >
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://fs.customer.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_1629646f-f163-4ba1-beaa-58c44bc14494">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>....</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>h....=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>/...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder" />
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Hello @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT we had some other problems the last week so I was not able to work on this problem too much but I' ll come back to yout answer, if I have done. But the force login hint was usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Your saml status response is received as below from the issuer, i.e., ADFS server: -

```
 ‘ <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder" />
</samlp:Status> ‘
```

It indicates that the identity provider, i.e., Active Directory which issues claims for the SAML authentication blocked the authentication for the concerned user/application because of wrong/missing user permissions or service provider configurations. Most probably, a permission to get access to the SAML SSO service provider is missing, which leads to this error, so check the user’s permission at the Identity provider.

Thus, would recommend you check your keycloak configuration in ADFS server once again with reference from the below link and follow the best configuration practices as stated below for the keycloak configuration with ADFS server: -

https://www.keycloak.org/2017/03/how-to-setup-ms-ad-fs-30-as-brokered

Best Practices: -

[How to force login per client with keycloak (¿best practice?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048205/how-to-force-login-per-client-with-keycloak-best-practice)